# Markdown Here browser plug-in syntax highlighting is not working in Chromium or FireFox. Works on Chromebook

Tags: latex, markdown, markup

I tried the following:

````
```tex
\includegraphics[width=200px]{untangler_manual_development_history_before}
%% This is a comment %%
```
````

but it only gives me a block of text, with no syntax highlighting, displayed in the picture below. The same is true for Java and other languages - Markdown Here renders a block of plain text without any highlights.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something? I tested this on Chromium and Firefox using Ubuntu 14.04, and the syntax highlighting does not work. On Chromebook, the syntax highlighting works just fine.

If this is a legitimate bug, any suggestions about how to file it would be great. I could not find the appropriate Markdown Here, and [this site](http://sourceforge.net/p/launchpad/support-requests/) was the closest support I could find, but there is no option to file a bug.

Here is a picture of the rendered Markdown on my example above:

[image]

Comment: Note that when you use fenced code blocks (the three back-ticks at the beginning and end), then you don't need the four spaces to make a code block.

Comment: Ah yes, this is fixed. I typically don't indent inside the fenced codeblocks. I got mixed up while posting with StackOverflow's format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are many different flavours of markdown around.

If the "GMail Chrome plugin" you're using is [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/): it apparently makes use of highlight.js [which supports](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/css-classes-reference.html?highlight=ruby#tex-tex) `tex`. So it should work. It's even in [Markdown Here's source code](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/blob/6ada1044e27c645489524d02471b9dda5d477bd6/src/common/highlightjs/highlight.js#L1014). Are you sure you're using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: Thank for the assurance, which led me to figure out the real problem - it is caused by Chromium not being able to highlight the syntax of my fenced code blocks. I still don't know why, but on my Chromebook (which uses Chrome), everything renders just fine. I may delete this question since it is no longer relevant to the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I too was affected by this problem, using Ubuntu 14.04, in both Thunderbird and Chromium.

I eventually fixed it simply by opening the Markdown Here preferences page, and changing the drop-down in the "Syntax Highlighting CSS" section from "Currently in use" to "Default (Github)".

Find the preferences in Chromium:
Menu->Settings->Extensions->Markdown Here->Options

And Thunderbird:
Tools->Add-ons->Extensions->Markdown Here->Preferences

I should add that I'm using Markdown Here version 2.11.2.

Comment: Thank you. This was way to hard to figure out. Also when I change mine it 'auto-saves' but doesn't actually save. #goinginsane